# percentage similarity in HTML files

Tags: java, html, text, metrics, similarity

I am trying to implement a defacement detector for websites. To achieve this, I should develop a tool in Java that compares similarity between two HTML files. I intend to strip URLs and JS to treat them seperately.

I am looking for a tool/ library /algorithm that I could use to calcuate a similarity metric (percentage ideally) in order to detect significant changes in websites.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So... you're asking for a tool that already does the thing you're looking to do? I'm not sure that this is a valid question.

Comment: I think it is a valid question. Even If I were to implement this tool myself, I would still need advice on the algorithm to use. And if this tool exists, why should I implement it (I don't have the skills required anyways, I am just an intern)

Comment: If you want a third-party tool, use PhantomJS. It is designed for automated site testing, and includes the ability to take screenshots of the site and compare with a reference image. See [this for more info](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomCSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since HTML is in essence just a text-based markup, the easiest way to go is the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). This algorithm determines the difference between 2 input strings by assigning a single point for every addition, subtraction or removal of a single character, and determines the 'shortest' distance for this result.

> Informally, the Levenshtein distance between two words is the minimum
>   number of single-character edits (insertion, deletion, substitution)
>   required to change one word into the other.

A sample implementation for Java [can be found here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Java).

By dividing the Levenshtein distance with the length of the largest input string you can calculate a difference percentage between the 2 strings.